# DatePicker/Timepicker is Visible all the time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fields with a `datepicker` & `timepicker`. Whenever I move to that page last used `datepicker or timepicker`  is visible all the time. For example if I had used `timepicker` on that page, then whenever I am going to that page `timepicker` is open.

My requirement is that when I will click on `TextBox` then the `datepicker` or `timepicker` should visible.

**JavaScript Function:**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("[id$=TextBox1]").pickadate({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});  
            $("[id$=TextBox3]").pickatime({ interval: 10 });
            $("[id$=TextBox4]").pickatime({ interval: 10 });            
        });
```

Where should I change my code?

Please help me to do so.

Thanks

**Update Code:**

For **TextBox1**

```
<tr> <td class="style10">
                    <strong>
                Today
                </strong>
                </td>
                <td class="style13">
                    <strong>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

For **TextBox3**

```
 <tr>
    <td class="style10">
                    <strong>
                    In Time:</strong></td>
                <td class="style13">
                    <strong>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

                    </strong>

                </td>
            </tr>
```

For **TextBox4**

```
 <tr>
                <td class="style10">
                    <strong>
                OutTime:</strong></td>
                <td class="style13">
                    <strong>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" onkeyup="sum"></asp:TextBox>
                    </strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
```

Comment: First of all, check if that particular field has focus when you visit the page!

Comment: @Rohit416 If I used other simple textbox then there is no problem.

Comment: Then it is not an issue with `datepicker` or `timepicker`. Possibly something else is going on with that field. As for now it is difficult to tell from here. Can you post some more relevant section of code?

Comment: @Rohit416 Have updated my question with css file. Plz review on that. Thanks

Comment: The link does not have the CSS. It is empty. Besides, it would be good if you can post the `HTML` of that mysterious text box.

Comment: @Rohit416 Sorry for the last empty link, now I have updated the html code for TextBox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115831/discussion-between-rohit416-and-kusum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate the picker in a var

```
var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')
```

And open or close it when you want:

```
picker.open()
picker.close()
```

In this way you can do something like this for each picker:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
           var picker =  $("[id$=TextBox1]").pickadate({format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'});           
  });
```

And add two event handlers for each input:

```
$('#TextBox1').focus(function() {
  picker.open()
});

$('#TextBox1').focusout(function() {
  picker.close()
});
```

If you dont want declarate a handler manually for each input (can be little 
toilsome), you can create a function for parametrize this:

```
function parametrizeHandlers(inputId, picker) {
    $('#'+inputId).focus(function() {
      picker.open()
    });

    $('#'+inputId).focusout(function() {
      picker.close()
    });
}
```

IMPORTANT: Im supose that you are using this API, full specification here:

[API- pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/#method-open-close)

If you're not using this API sure you can do something like this.

Comment: Yes I am using that API... have taken the reference from that site.

Comment: Then you can use something that this that i explain before, I have used with other apis. if open() and close() don't destroy de picker sure that .stop() and .start() do it.

Comment: I used your solution , but that's not resolve my problem. Still getting that error.

Comment: The behavour you want is that the picker only displays when you click on the input and dissapear when the input lose focus?? Maybe i didn't understand you. You try with stop() and start() methods??

Comment: Yes I also used stop () and start ().